# Why is WebClient.DownloadStringAsync Queuing Requests and how do I speed it up?

Tags: vb.net, webclient

I am using WebClient.DownloadStringAsync to send requests to a URL.  I am sending thousands of requests at a time.  Basically there is a delay between when I send the request and when the callback fires.  The more requests I send, the longer the delay becomes. After an hour of sending requests, the delay can get up to about 20 minutes.  After several hours, the delay is more than an hour.  I would like to know how I can process them as quickly as they get queued up.

Here are some details:

1. I've tried the non async code - it takes way longer (about a second per request), so please don't suggest.
2. The time it takes to fire off 5000 requests is 91 seconds
3. The time it takes to complete 5000 requests is 177 seconds

   Peek at the Code Below:

   ```
   'Takes about 91 Seconds to get through this loop
   Do Until i=5000
        Dim wcWebClient As New System.Net.WebClient
        AddHandler wcWebClient.DownloadStringCompleted, AddressOf webClient_DownloadStringCompleted
        wcWebClient.DownloadStringAsync(New Uri(sURL))
        i=i+1
   Loop

           'Takes 177 seconds before all 5000 are processed
       Private Sub webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs)

       End Sub
   ```

Comment: `i` never changes according to the code above, so I highly doubt you are getting anything with that code. Also you should be disposing the `webclient` as well as removing the handlers you are adding as well.

Comment: My loop is a lot longer so I basically just put the i=5000 to show that I loop 5000 times

Comment: `Also you should be disposing the webclient as well as removing the handlers you are adding as well` what is your thoughts about this?

Comment: Probably a good idea - TY! - but I don't know if that would solve the original issue

Comment: Could it be that the server is taking some time to respond?

Comment: 9x10 it's the server that will take time to get back to you. It could be that the server is slowing these request down as well; to many request in a short time etc. There are a few ways to get around this, but then again that's not what SO is about. It would be opinion based or you would be asking for off-site tuts etc of which are all off topic here. If you would update your post on what you have tried, we could certainly help you.

Comment: It could be that the the server is taking some time to respond but would the WebClient really store and wait for an hour? It seems like they would expire or fail, but they don't